# Execution of javascript code after synchronous ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am calling for a ajax function on button click using JavaScript. The php script evaluates the parameters and echoes out either 1 for success or 0 for failure. To enforce other JavaScript codes to be run, I am using synchronous method (false). Yet, after the successful execution of php code, further JavaScript lines, that is, the alerts do not run. How to make this possible?
Note: I am not sure if this question has been asked before.

```
var parameters = "user="+usr+"&id="+id;
ajaxRequest.open("POST", 'chk.php', false);
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
ajaxRequest.send(parameters);
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        if (ajaxRequest.responseText == 1) {
            alert('Success');
        } else {
            alert('Failure');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using synchronous ajax? It should never be used, as it will lock the entire UI for the user.

Comment: Please add more detail to your question... you mentioned that "further JavaScript" code doesn't execute. Refer to the code snippet and indicate which lines don't execute. Also, what steps have you taken to debug the code?

Comment: HaZardouS, the alerts don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To enforce other JavaScript codes to be run, I am using synchronous method (false).

There's no need to do that in your quoted code.

> Yet, after the successful execution of php code, further JavaScript lines do not run.

That's because you're using a synchronous request, and hooking up `onreadystatechange` in the wrong place. If you'd made it async, it would have worked (but still should be changed).

Making the XHR request synchronous means `send` doesn't return until the work is complete. You don't hook up your `onreadystatechange` handler until **after** `send`, so it's not hooked up when the request completes, so your code inside the handler isn't run.

If you want to keep it synchronous, move your code setting up `onreadystatechange` to **before** `send`. (You should do that even if you make it async.)

If you want to code in the handler to run when the request completes, there's no need to make it a synchronous request, and there are good reasons *not* to.

**Recommended changes:**

```
var parameters = "user="+usr+"&id="+id;
ajaxRequest.open("POST", 'chk.php', true);    // <== use async
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){  // <== Moved up
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        if (ajaxRequest.responseText == 1) {
            alert('Success');
        } else {
            alert('Failure');
        }
    }
};
ajaxRequest.send(parameters);
```

But leave the `false` on `open` if you really, really want a synchronous request.